# Determine WM_SYSCOMMAND or WM_ENTERMENULOOP what menu item activated?

Tags: c++, api, winapi

In Win32 API, in windows messages assume a menu of

&File -- &Edit -- &View

The user clicks File.  A WM_SYSCOMMAND (WParam = SC_MOUSEMENU or maybe SC_KEYMENU) and then a WM_ENTERMENULOOP is sent.
The user clicks Edit.  Same.

I would like to know which one is about to be displayed right before it pops up.  Is it &File, is &Edit that was activated?

It doesn't look like either WM_SYSCOMMAND or WM_ENTERMENULOOP pass information that provides this.  Is there a way I can determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [WM_INITMENUPOPUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646347.aspx).

This message is sent to the owner window. Its `wParam` parameter contains the `HMENU` of the popup menu that is about to be displayed.

The low-order word of its `lParam` parameter specifies the index of the menu item that opens the popup, and its high-order word is `TRUE` if the popup menu is the system menu, or `FALSE` otherwise.